# ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress

Tags: php, cookies, wordpress

I have a WordPress site. Suddenly, it stopped working everything that was working in the previous day. The next day I am unable to login. It gives the following error:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

I don't think there is any problem with its plugins. I have a similar website with the same theme and plugins, and the site is working fine.

My WordPress was automatically updated two days ago from 3.7 to 3.8, but it worked fine for two days. How can it cause a problem after two days?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled?

Comment: Clear out the cookies from your browser and try login again.

Comment: Try restarting the server

Comment: I deleted all cookies from my browser but issue is same

Comment: there is one more wordpress site on same server but this problem is not there

Comment: Try restarting the server.

Comment: ok, doing in a minute

Comment: can you tell me how can i restart it . I am having cpanel access. how can i restart server on shared hosting

Comment: Depends. What kind of server are you running (Apache, Oracle Server, etc)

Comment: There should be a start/stop option on your server software.

Comment: got hosting from godaddy , Cpanel may be apache with phpmyadmin

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea what changes he might have done or what his host provides.

Comment: Actually this was working fine 1 days before .

Comment: Make sure you have JavaScript and cookies enabled in your browser. If you have plug-ins installed in your browser, temporarily disable them and try loading the website again. Also try opening the site in a different browser and see what happens.

Comment: Things have a tendency to go wrong. It's Murphies Law. A restart usually fixes things.

Comment: I tried it in mozilla and chrome both , issue exist in both

Comment: Use a command from the cPanel. Take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html

Comment: Any other solution instead of restart

Comment: Try a different browser, a different computer, and a different connection. You've done one of these (Firefox and Chrome), now try the other two. (If you are on a shared host, as your use of cPanel implies, you can't restart Apache).

Comment: [Possible solution to try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733731/localhost-multisite-wordpress-cookies-login-error).

Comment: Thanks halfer , I am not having multisite . But i tried this solution it does not work . According to me this solutions works . If we shift from one host to other or in multisite

Comment: if you are using cloudflare or any other similar , try clearing cache from there ? purging cache worked for me.

Comment: THanks Pokhrel, I am not using cloudflare. I cleared the cache two time . But sorry same problem

Comment: Recently solved issue from here : https://www.scratchcode.io/cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser/
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be the following issues in your site.

```
Coding Error
Unnecessary Spaces in Code
Caching & Security Plugin
```

Check more here: https://www.scratchcode.io/cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser/